# Not able to solve No_Pubkey

Tags: keyserver

Tried update using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

got following response:

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                 
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                                        
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                             
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                           
Hit:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                                          
Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]                                                         
Get:9 https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org bionic InRelease [4,244 B]           
Err:9 https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org bionic InRelease       
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 74A941BA219EC810
Reading package lists... Done                                  
W: GPG error: https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 74A941BA219EC810
E: The repository 'https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Then I tried:

```
~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 74A941BA219EC810
```

And got

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.LvVh1YzHpU/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 74A941BA219EC810
^[[A^[[Bgpg: packet(13) too large
gpg: read_block: read error: Invalid packet
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Tried that earlier. It simply gave "No Valid OpenPGP data found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reasons it seems keyserver is taking longer than expected for some reason at least for me. You can try importing key for tor using:

```
curl https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89.asc | gpg --import
gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | apt-key add -
```